# Could someone advise me on sources for crystallography and surface sciences?

Tags: materials, surface-chemistry, crystallography, books

I'm a physicist learning crystallography and surface science on the side of my research and I came across the concepts: surface reconstruction in hexagonal materials, unit mesh of surfaces, etc.

I was given problems to solve but they are too advanced for me. These are based on the book *Modern Techniques of Surface Science 3rd ed.* by Dr. Woodruff.

Can someone advise me with some other sources of information to better understand Lattice Planes and Miller Indices, to the level shown in the [Cambridge website](https://www.doitpoms.ac.uk/tlplib/miller_indices/lattice_index.php).

Comment: Recommend you start with something simpler: *bulk* crystallography. ;)

Comment: Would that be the title of the book? Are there any online sources for bulk crystallography?

Comment: *Bulk* was meant as a synonym for "basic", "general", "simple". That's still no picnic, I promise. Take out your old physics 101 textbook and revise what's in there, then go on.

Comment: 'Crystallography'  W. Borchardt-Ott, publ Spinger for lots on space groups etc. and with a more on x-ray diffraction as well as crystallography, 'Essentials of Crystallography' , D. McKie & C. McKie, publ Blackwell.

Comment: Thank you very much, so far I had only found "Fundamental of Material Science and Engineering by W. Callister Jr." .